# Implement Google maps API on React app

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, npm

I'm a beginner on react and trying to implement Google Maps API to my [React app](https://github.com/ohsik/reactpg)

I have a search input and place for the map on the page `http://localhost:8080/`.

How do I implement Google maps autocomplete search into search input box and how the result on the map below. I also like to get json data of geolocation, business website, phone number, hours and etc from Google Maps API.

How do I implement this with React??

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use a third party library. First you, you need to embed the script in your index.html

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]&libraries=places"></script>
```

Create a component for your autocomplete input element.

Inside this components componentDidMount method

```
this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      this.autocompleteInput.current,
      {
        types: ["geocode"],
        componentRestrictions: { country: "uk" }
      }
    );
    this.autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", this.handlePlaceChanged);
```

Autocomplete class has an event called place_changed. When you click on one of the results, you can trigger autocomplete classes getPlace() function and fetch coordinates and bunch of other fields.

```
handlePlaceChanged() {
    const place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
    this.props.onPlaceChanged(place);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if you can find GMaps for react native like this one: https://github.com/teamrota/react-native-gmaps